# Save entity with Spring data, persistence & db contraints

Tags: spring-data, persistence

In my project I have e.g. an `Employee` which has several `Mobile` which has additional attributes, e.g.

```
Jon Doe, +911, private
Jon Doe, 123456, company
Jon Doe, 8978, company,
Mara Smith, 7888, private
Mara Smith, 458, company
```

and therefore I create

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  private int id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="emp")
  private List<Mobile> lstMobiles;
  ...
}
```

and for the `Mobile` I have

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MobileKey.class)
public class Mobile {
  @Id
  private String phoneNo;
  @Id
  @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
  private Employee emp;
  ...
}
class MobileKey{
  private String phoneNo;
  private int emp;
....
}
```

The database has tables `Employee`, `Mobile`. The table `Mobile` first two columns are

1. emp_id (as int)
2. phoneNo (as String)

up till now nothing special except that the database has a foreign constraint, namely that the emp_id has to exist in the table `Employee`. Otherwise the phoneNo does not make much sense.

The major problem I'm facing right now is that I need to store `Jon Doe` or `Mara Smith`. If I use e.g.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}
```

with some `Autowired` variable as e.g. `employeeRepo.save(newEmployee)` than I get from the database **a constraint violation**. This is due to the fact that the `Mobile` is attempted to be inserted before the `Employee` is created in the table :-(

I guess that the design of `Employee` and the `Mobile` is somehow wrong - especially with the list and the relation. But could be as well be related with the Spring-Data configuration.

Comment: 1. You are missing a `@ManyToOne` on the Mobile > Employee relationship. 2. You should ensure both sides of the relationship are set i.e. `employee.addPhone(mobile); mobile.setEmployee(employee);`

Comment: yeah, true setting `mobile.setEmployee(employee)` helps.  I do not think that the `@ManyToOne` annotation is required, but I might be wrong. Additionally I figured out that the `id` of the `employee` needs to be set or `@GeneratedValue` - setting the last annotation fix the issue finally.